# Setting tab size in vim on mingW32 windows

Tags: vim, mingw32

I am using VIM on windows using the mingw32. Is there a way to change the default tab size ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `.vimrc` (if you want e.g., 3 tab size):

```
set tabstop=3
set shiftwidth=3
set expandtab "for converting tabs to spaces
set noexpandtab "for not converting tabs to spaces
```

Answer (score 4):

On MS Windows, without mingw32, the resource file to edit is called "`_vimrc`" and can be found in the installation directory of Vim, usually under Program Files.

For example

`c:\Program Files (x86)\Vim`